# Automated 1-sided 90% CIs from lm or glm function in R

Tags: r

I have been searching for a way to get a direct output of a 1-sided 90% CI around a regression slope beta using either the lm or glm functions.

Right now, I have used confint and set the level to 0.80 and just used either the upper or lower bound of the interval.

We essentially need to evaluate if the slope differs from 0 in the negative direction. This analysis is a little odd and our team wants an automated output (i.e., no interpretation needed).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what you have done, use 0.8 will work.. where lies the problem ?

Comment: It mainly comes from the 'non-statistically minded' folks not understanding the one side of a 2-sided 80CI is equivalent to a 1-sided 90CI. They would prefer to have something spit directly from R that does not require any statistical interpretation. 

Since this is a bit of an unconventional request, I feel like using confint is the best option available.

Comment: you can calculate that from scratch, but i don't see the point of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you have done is ok:

```
fit = lm(mpg ~ hp , data=mtcars)
confint(fit,level=0.8)
                   10 %        90 %
(Intercept) 27.95774598 32.23997510
hp          -0.08148877 -0.05496779
```

you can slightly alter the [source code for confint](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/confint.R), basically derive the t statistic for alpha =0.1 and add that multiplied by the standard error:

```
one_sided_conf = function(fit,alpha,upper=TRUE){
    cf = coef(fit)
    ses = sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))
    if(upper){
          cr_t = qt(1-alpha, fit$df.residual)
    }else{
          cr_t = qt(alpha, fit$df.residual)
    }
    cf + cr_t * ses
}

one_sided_conf(fit,0.1,upper=TRUE)
(Intercept)          hp 
32.23997510 -0.05496779
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I think the second option that you have described would be more acceptable to the non-stats folks.